# ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1170 columns

Tags: python

When I try to import a geojson file and convert it into a dataframe, the issue appears, I want a dataframe with columns: Zipcode, Latitude, Longitude. Here are my codes:

```
import urllib.request, json 
import pandas as pd


with urllib.request.urlopen("http://bostonopendata-boston.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/53ea466a189b4f43b3dfb7b38fa7f3b6_1.geojson") as url:
    wuppertal_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

neighborhoods_data = wuppertal_data['features']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for data in neighborhoods_data:

    zipcode = data['properties']['ZIP5']
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data['geometry']['coordinates'])
    temp_df = temp_df.T
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_df.iloc[:,0].tolist(), columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])

    temp_df['Zipcode'] = zipcode

    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\PYTHON3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    496         result = _convert_object_array(
--> 497             content, columns, dtype=dtype, coerce_float=coerce_float
    498         )

D:\PYTHON3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _convert_object_array(content, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    580             raise AssertionError(
--> 581                 f"{len(columns)} columns passed, passed data had "
    582                 f"{len(content)} columns"

AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1170 columns

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-b1c5869e9ca3> in <module>
     14     temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data['geometry']['coordinates'])
     15     temp_df = temp_df.T
---> 16     temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_df.iloc[:,0].tolist(), columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])
     17 
     18     temp_df['Neighborhood'] = neighborhood_name

D:\PYTHON3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    472                     if is_named_tuple(data[0]) and columns is None:
    473                         columns = data[0]._fields
--> 474                     arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
    475                     columns = ensure_index(columns)
    476 

D:\PYTHON3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    459         return [], []  # columns if columns is not None else []
    460     if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
--> 461         return _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float=coerce_float, dtype=dtype)
    462     elif isinstance(data[0], abc.Mapping):
    463         return _list_of_dict_to_arrays(

D:\PYTHON3.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py in _list_to_arrays(data, columns, coerce_float, dtype)
    498         )
    499     except AssertionError as e:
--> 500         raise ValueError(e) from e
    501     return result
    502 

ValueError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 1170 columns
```

I don't quite understand the error. Can anyone help me out? I don't know what part is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that `temp_df.iloc[:,0]` sometimes had more than 2 columns - in which case it was throwing an error, since you indexed only 2 of them - so to limit number of read columns from `pd.Series` to `2` just do: `temp_df.iloc[:,0].str[:2]` instead.

Full code:

```py
import urllib.request, json 
import pandas as pd


with urllib.request.urlopen("http://bostonopendata-boston.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/53ea466a189b4f43b3dfb7b38fa7f3b6_1.geojson") as url:
    wuppertal_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

neighborhoods_data = wuppertal_data['features']

results = pd.DataFrame()
for data in neighborhoods_data:
    zipcode = data['properties']['ZIP5']
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data['geometry']['coordinates'])
    temp_df = temp_df.T
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_df.iloc[:,0].str[:2].tolist(), columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])
    temp_df['Zipcode'] = zipcode
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: no worries, please upvote, and mark it as an answer, if it solves your problem :)